# Slurm new user on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: malware, user-management, accounts

I am a very new user of Ubuntu (escaped from Windows recently) and yesterday when I was turning on my PC I found new user listed in login options with a nickname "Slurm" (I am the only user with a password). I tried to Google it but there is nothing about it (only about slurm itself, but it is different). Maybe somebody can explain me about it. Can it be some kind of virus? Because it is strange, it's like new user with his own password. I deleted that account, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Slurm is a workload manager used in computation clusters. When it is installed, it creates a "Slurm" user for management of the service. Check if you have installed this package and, if so, remove it.

```
sudo apt remove slurm*
```

Best regards